# Tab layout loads same data on all tabs

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-tablayout

I have three tabs. The first tab displays the images from the internet which are searched from the search box and the other two tabs display random images. The problem is that when I open any tab for the first time the images are loaded properly but then when I move to the next tab the images of the previous tab are displayed in this tab and then all the tabs display the same images.
How to solve this problem?

This is my main activity

```
ViewPager viewPager;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    setUpViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment(), "SEARCH"); // `new SearchFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new RandomFragment(), "RANDOM"); // `new RandomFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new DailyFragment(), "DAILY"); // `new DailyFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

This is the first tab

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    search_image = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_image);
    searchButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSearch);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.loadingIndicator);

    updateView();

    return view;
}


public void updateView(){
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable
            .Builder(getContext())
            .build());
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            WallpaperInterface wallpaperInterface = Client.getClient().create(WallpaperInterface.class);
            Call<WallpaperDetails> wallpaperDetailsCall = wallpaperInterface.getImages(API_KEY, search_image.getText().toString());
            wallpaperDetailsCall.enqueue(new Callback<WallpaperDetails>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Response<WallpaperDetails> response) {
                    List<Wallpapers> wallpapersList = response.body().getHits();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new WallpaperAdapter(wallpapersList, getContext()));
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is the second tab

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_random, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRandom);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.loadingIndicator);

    updateView();

    return view;
}

public void updateView(){
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable
            .Builder(getContext())
            .build());

    WallpaperInterface wallpaperInterface = Client.getClient().create(WallpaperInterface.class);
    Call<WallpaperDetails> wallpaperDetailsCall = wallpaperInterface.getImages(API_KEY, "wallpapers");
    wallpaperDetailsCall.enqueue(new Callback<WallpaperDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Response<WallpaperDetails> response) {
            List<Wallpapers> wallpapersList = response.body().getHits();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new WallpaperAdapter(wallpapersList, getContext()));
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error: ", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the third tab

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDaily);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.loadingIndicator);

    updateView();

    return view;
}

public void updateView(){
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable
            .Builder(getContext())
            .build());

    WallpaperInterface wallpaperInterface = Client.getClient().create(WallpaperInterface.class);
    Call<WallpaperDetails> wallpaperDetailsCall = wallpaperInterface.getImages(API_KEY, "daily");
    wallpaperDetailsCall.enqueue(new Callback<WallpaperDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Response<WallpaperDetails> response) {
            List<Wallpapers> wallpapersList = response.body().getHits();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new WallpaperAdapter(wallpapersList, getContext()));
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WallpaperDetails> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error: ", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: And you service is returning different images as expected?

Comment: No. The service returns the right images but when i change the tabs, then all the tabs get the same images as the one which i open first. Like if i tap on the random tab first then i will get right images and when i go to daily tab then initially the images are right but when i scroll the view then all the images of random tab are loaded in daily tab. This happens for all tabs.

Comment: I mean yes the service returns different images at first bt after changing tabs the same images are loaded in all tabs